# When expressing "by using the Python programming language", should I use "with", "in" or something else?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51567750/11562913) uses this title

> Extract specific pages of PDF and save it `with` Python

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/176918/11562913) uses this title

> Finding the index of an item given a list containing it `in` Python

Both of the examples above are "using the Python programming language".

So, when expressing "by using the Python programming language", should I use "with", "in" or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in meaning between the two given examples.

In the first case one is using python to process external data. You are processing the pdf **with** python.

The second is about the internal handling of data. You are writing the program **in** python.

There is some flexibility here, and this should not be treated as a hard "rule".